# Drush complains about missing timezone despite it being set

Tags: cloudbees

I'm running Drush Make as part of a Cloudbees Jenkins job. It's constantly dumping errors like this:

> You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone.

I don't understand why this is- I explicitly set the timezone in the first build step, as recommended by the Cloudbees documentation:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p /tmp/php
echo "date.timezone = America/Chicago" > /tmp/php/php.ini
export PHPRC=/tmp/php
php -i
```

This outputs the following, which confirms that the timezone is set.

> date
>
> date/time support => enabled
>   "Olson" Timezone Database Version => 0.system
>   Timezone Database => internal
>   Default timezone => America/Chicago
>
> Directive => Local Value => Master Value
>   date.timezone => America/Chicago => America/Chicago

So why on earth would PHP still be complaining in the Drush Make step?

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins executes each build step as a separate bash script, meaning that the environment variable exported in the first build step isn't available in subsequent build steps.

The solution is to use the Environment Injector Jenkins plugin to set the environment variable, so that it's set for the duration of the job.